# Evaluate the line integral $\int_C zdx+xdy+ydz $

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

Calculate
$\int_C zdx+xdy+ydz $ where $C= \{(x,y,z) \;| \;x=t, y=t^2, z=t^3, 0 \leq t \leq 1 \} $

### So

$$x=t $$
$$dx=1 $$
$$y=t^2 $$
$$dy=2t $$
$$z=t^3 $$

### $$dz=3t^2 $$

$$\int_{0}^{1} [t^3(1)+t(2t)+t^2(3t^2)]dt $$

$$\int_{0}^{1} (t^3+2t^2+3t^4)dt $$

$$[\frac{t^4}{4}+\frac{2t^3}{3}+\frac{3t^5}{5}]_{0}^{1} $$

$$=\frac{91}{60} $$

Comment: I didn't check the arithmetic, but it it looks right to me.  Did you have a question?

Comment: Actually I didn't know if the process its correct

Comment: This is correct

Answer (score 2):

This is correct, although you should write $dx=1dt$, $dy=2tdt$ and $dz=3t^2dt$, to be precise.